# Python loop for getting list of elements on few pages

Tags: python, list, loops, selenium

In my application, I have a table with users, but the table can have more than 1 page with users.
I want to get a list with all users in all pages with Selenium Webdriver Python.
I need some algorithm which is gonna count users in the first page then click on second page count there and until the pages is done, and return entire list.
I have some idea but don't know how to realize that,
something like below:

```
def users(driver):
    list_users = []
    for list_users in range(n):
       #selector for click on second page
       num = num + 1
       #getting all users from 1 page
       driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".even .odd")
       #click on second page until pages is exist
       driver.find_elements_by_link_text("%s" % num)
           until NoSuchElementException
     return list_users
```

I know it's not even close for working algorithm but i tried to explain what i want

Comment: Can you provide a link to the data you are trying to access?

Comment: @djk47463
[link](http://hrm.seleniumminutes.com/symfony/web/index.php/admin/viewSystemUsers)
login: Admin
pass: Password

Comment: do you need the users name or just the total amount of users?

Comment: @djk47463 it could be just total amount

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need the total number of people and that you have already logged in...

```
people = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
              [@id="frmList_ohrmListComponent"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]').text
print people
```

yields "1-50 of 53" which is from the websites index seen here

[image]

That tells you the total amount of people in your list

then to get the total use

```
print people.split()[2]
```

which give you a value of 53

-------------EDIT-----------------------

to get the users loop through the tags and pages

```
from math import ceil
pages = ceil(float(people.split()[2])/50)

users = []
for p in range(1,int(pages)+1):
    driver.execute_script('javascript:submitPage(%s)' % p) #change page
    for i in range(1,51):
        try:
            user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
                           [@id="resultTable"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td[2]' % i) 
                                          #change tag____^
            users.append(user.text)
        except:
            break

print users
```

Comment: I'm sorry i explained not clearly, i need the list with all the users inside

Comment: Unresolved reference "people" issue in line pages = ceil(float(people.split()[2])/50)

Comment: did you not use the first line of code I supplied, with the variable named people?

Answer (score 0):

can we use something like that?:

```
def users1(driver):
l=()
while l != NoSuchElementException:
    userslist = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".even .odd")
    for i in range(1, 50):
        l = driver.find_element_by_link_text("%s" % i).click()
    return userslist
```